# Javascript Replace Removing all HTML tags?

Tags: javascript

I made a simple highlighting function for doing a keyword search on my webpage.  I want to remove the tags `<mark>` and `</mark>` to remove the highlighting when the clear button is pressed.  For some reason replace is removing all of the HTML, not just that tag.  How can I just remove the one tag?

```
$(toolsProjects).each(function (index,tool) {
    var element1=$(document.getElementById(tool['uid']))[0];
    var title = $(element1.getElementsByClassName("resource_title")[0]).text().replace('<mark>',"");
    $(element1.getElementsByClassName("resource_title")[0]).html(title.replace("</mark>", ""));
    var desc = $(element1.getElementsByClassName("text__container")[0]).text().replace('<mark>',"");
    $(element1.getElementsByClassName("text__container")[0]).html("<p>"+desc.replace("</mark>", "")+"</p>");
  });
```

My original code looks like:

```
<div class="more"><p>Learn more about the portal at <a href="https://www.uvm.edu/femc/mbw">https://www.uvm.edu/femc/mbw</a>.</p></div><a class="read">Read More</a></div>
```

and after looks like:

```
Learn more about the portal at https://www.uvm.edu/femc/mbw.Read More
```

Comment: title and desc are text not html.

Comment: First of all you can not replace tag with text function, Second could you share your html where `<mark>...</marl>  tag ` usually gonna use on keyword re-search, I am open to solve your problem 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
/**
 * @param {HTMLElement} el
 */
const removeAndInsertChildren = (el) => {
  const {
    nextSibling,
    parentElement
  } = el;
  const children = Array.from(el.childNodes);
  el.remove();

  if (children.length === 0) return;

  for (const child of children) {
    if (!nextSibling) {
      parentElement.appendChild(child);
    } else {
      parentElement.insertBefore(child, nextSibling);
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('mark')) {
      removeAndInsertChildren(el);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem <mark>ipsum <i>An inner element</i></mark> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada. Non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis. Tincidunt
  augue interdum velit euismod in. In arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Eros donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in. Tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies. In hac habitasse
  platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in. Scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis. Nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur
  purus ut. Ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et. Platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus. Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh <mark>ipsum</mark>  consequat nisl vel. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis.

  <p>Lorem <mark>ipsum <b>I am an inner el</b></mark> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada. Non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis. Tincidunt
    augue interdum velit euismod in. In arcu cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras. Purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Eros donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in. Tempus urna et pharetra pharetra massa massa ultricies. In hac habitasse
    platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus. Ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in. Scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci sagittis. Nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam. Felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur
    purus ut. Ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et. Platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est. Integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Id neque aliquam vestibulum morbi blandit cursus. Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh <mark>ipsum</mark>    consequat nisl vel. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis.
    
<button id="clear">Clear</button>
```

I think this is the type of thing you were wanting? Basically just remove the `mark` elements and replace them with their contents.

Comment: personally I'd use `const text = el.innerHTML; el.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", text); el.remove();` inside the loop - thereby preserving any HTML inside the `<mark>` - which is what I think the question was asking

Comment: Good point. I don't really want to serialize and reparse the DOM  so I'm not gonna use `innerHTML` but your point stands. I'll update it

Comment: I may be wrong of course, no idea what the OP's HTML looks like :p

Comment: well best to support it in any case since it doesn't hurt either way